# Firebase/Firebase.h file not found

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native

Using Xcode 10.1, I am trying to add firebase to my iOS app, I keep getting the error:

```
#import React/RCTUtils.h file not found
#import Firebase/Firebase.h file not found
```

**UPDDATE:** Added the firebase files, however now I am getting the error with `RNFBAuth`,  `Firebase/Firebase.h file not found` See attached.

[image]

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods or are you manually adding the Firebase frameworks? And are you using react-native-firebase?

Comment: Yes I am using `react-native-firebase`

Comment: I have tried both methods with no luck

Comment: Okay, just a few more questions ;-) Which parts of firebase are you using? And why do you need RCTUtils?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed Firebase without CocoaPods since I wasn't using it anywhere else, and these are the most important lessons I learned:

- Most default settings in Firebase expect that the libraries are inside a folder named Firebase. So to avoid any additional pain, I suggest creating that folder inside your ios/ folder. In this Firebase folder you need to add the frameworks you are using and also the Firebase.h file. For example, in my case I have the Analytics and Messaging folders with their respective frameworks, and then the Firebase.h file.
- You probably also need to update the Header Search Paths of your iOS Target (this ensure that correct folders are being checked for those files), and add entries for Firebase and react-native-firebase:

  - $(SRCROOT)/Firebase
  - $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase

Comment: Great, do i just move the folders out of `node_modules` into the `firebase` folder?

Comment: No, you need to download the Firebase SDK for iOS, and then add only the required parts to the Firebase folder

Comment: Added those files, however, now I'm getting the error with RNFBAuth, any ideas? Not sure where that prject has come from.

Comment: How do I access `RNFBAuth`? I cant see any project files anywhere